# Zoom magnify main video hide on mouseout in jQuery

Tags: jquery, magnify

Hi I have used the Jquery plugin for zoom magnify which is working correctly but I also want add video in that section,

I tried to write this script ,when I mouseover the thumbnail video display and when go to play main video which is right side it  hides,So how will it remain display. Please guide.

```
 //Product detail page
$(document).on('mouseover','a.p-video',function () {
    $('.p-video-iframe').show();
});
$(document).on('mouseout','a.p-video',function () {
    $('.p-video-iframe').hide();
});
```

[image: Check this image]

Comment: You could try to hide `.p-video-iframe` on mouseout of `.p-video-iframe`.

Comment: @Tom Please guide unable to figure out

Comment: `$(".p-video-iframe").on("mouseout", function () { $(".p-video-iframe").hide(); });`